# Limiting access by IP in kubernetes on GCP's GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running kubernetes (k8s) on top of Google Cloud Patform's Container Engine (GKE) and Load Balancers (GLB). I'd like to limit the access at a k8s ingress to an IP whitelist.

Is this something I can do in k8s or GLB directly, or will I need to run things via a proxy which does it for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to whitelist source IP's in nginx-ingress is using below annotation.

`ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range`

**But unfortunately, Google Cloud Load Balancer does not have support for it, AFAIK.**

If you're using nginx ingress controller you can use it.

The value of the annotation can be comma separated CIDR ranges.

More on [whitelist annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#whitelist-source-range).

[Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904903) for progress on Google Cloud Load Balancer support for whitelisting source IP's.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` as specified here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range

You need to be sure that you are forwarding external IPs to your services - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip

And if you are using NGINX Ingress, make sure you set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on your ingress controllers service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cloud Armor, Add a Policy, create your Allow/Deny Rules, then simply attach k8s LB in the target.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GCP’s firewall rules cannot be applied on the Global Load Balancer it attaches with an Ingress that is created on GKE. If you want to restrict access to only specific IP addresses (for example : users connecting via VPN, in this case the VPN gateway’s IP address) then there is no out of the box solution on GCP, especially GKE.

**Nginx and Http header “x-forwarded-for” to the rescue**

If you are using GKE, chances are that you have a Microservices architecture and you are using an API Gateway, chances are that Nginx is the API Gateway. All that needs to be done is to configure nginx to only allow requests that have the following IPs

**user.ext.static.ip** → Public IP of the client

**app.global.static.ip** → Global static IP assigned to Ingress

nginx conf

```
location /my_service {
  rewrite_by_lua_file validate_ip.lua;
  proxy_pass http://my_service
}
```

validate_ip.lua

```
local cjson = require "cjson"

local status=""

local headers=ngx.req.get_headers()

local source_ips=headers["x-forwarded-for"]

if source_ips ~= "111.222.333.444, 555.666.777.888" then
  status="NOT_ALLOWED"
end

if status ~= "" then
  ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
  ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  ngx.say(cjson.encode({ status = "ERROR",message=status.."YOUR_MESSAGE" }))
  return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end
```

For more details [read here](https://medium.com/@rishavverma/whitelist-ips-on-gcp-kubernetes-ingress-4f7c6f4eb0f)

Comment: you should not trust headers, it can be forged

Answer (score 0):

You could use CORS and only allow the IP from the frontend to hit your microservices.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into doing this and I found a fairly easy way to do it, assuming your service is of type: `LoadBalancer`, all you need to do nowadays is to add the following field to the `spec` definition.

```yaml
loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - x.x.x.x/32
```

You can add as many sources cidr's as needed, in case you are curious this is translated to a firewall rule that allows traffic from those sources, you can find the rule in the network that your service is using.